# CAS difference between Candidate/Registered and Sorted and registered Authentication Handler

Tags: cas

I am having a blocker situation with CAS 6.0.x and I cant get past it.  I Am unable to log in with a UsernamePasswordCredential.  I have even removed all actual checks,  and simply return a credential.

Here is the coide:

```
public class MyDatabaseAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler {

  public MyDatabaseAuthenticationHandler(String name, ServicesManager servicesManager, PrincipalFactory principalFactory, Integer order, DataSource dataSource) {
    super(name, servicesManager, principalFactory, order, dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(UsernamePasswordCredential credential, String originalPassword) throws GeneralSecurityException, PreventedException {
    return createHandlerResult(credential, this.principalFactory.createPrincipal(username), null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final Credential credential)  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Here is my config:

```
@Configuration("My6CasConfiguration")
public class My6CasConfiguration implements AuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("principalFactory")
  private PrincipalFactory principalFactory;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationHandler getMyJdbcAuthenticationHandler() {
    return new MyDatabaseAuthenticationHandler("MYJDBCAuthenticationManager",
                                             servicesManager, 
                                             principalFactory, 
                                             0, 
                                             customDataSource());
  }

  @Override
  public void configureAuthenticationExecutionPlan(AuthenticationEventExecutionPlan plan) {
    plan.registerAuthenticationHandler(getMyJdbcAuthenticationHandler());
  }
}
```

This is what I am getting in the logs:

```
[36m2019-06-02 11:07:38,544 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventExecutionPlan] - <Candidate/Registered authentication handlers for this transaction are [[org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler@277fd34b, com.xxx.cas.handler.MyDatabaseAuthenticationHandler@58b0ac93, org.apereo.cas.adaptors.x509.authentication.handler.support.X509CredentialsAuthenticationHandler@41078c16]]>^[[m
[[36m2019-06-02 11:07:38,544 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventExecutionPlan] - <Sorted and registered authentication handler resolvers for this transaction are [[org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.ByCredentialSourceAuthenticationHandlerResolver@663cfaa1, org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.RegisteredServiceAuthenticationHandlerResolver@272f62cc]]>^[[m
[[36m2019-06-02 11:07:38,545 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventExecutionPlan] - <Authentication handler resolvers for this transaction are [[org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.ByCredentialSourceAuthenticationHandlerResolver@663cfaa1, org.apereo.cas.authentication.handler.RegisteredServiceAuthenticationHandlerResolver@272f62cc]]>^[[m
[[1;31m2019-06-02 11:07:38,549 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports [UsernamePasswordCredential(username=asdf, source=MYJDBCAuthenticationManager)] of type [UsernamePasswordCredential]. Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event.>^[[m
[[1;31m2019-06-02 11:07:38,550 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <[MYJDBCAuthenticationManager]: [warnings is marked @NonNull but is null]>
```

What am I doing wrong that this is not working?  And what is that difference between Candidate/Registered, Sorted/Registered, and handler resolvers?

The act that my custom class only shows up in the first,  makes me think I have configured something wrong.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I am implementing custom AuthenticationHandler using CAS **5.3.x**, so it might not be completely compatible with your case, anyway I see the following difference from me and your implementation. Please check if these can help you first. (1) I have a `spring.factories` with `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` **I guess you have `spring.factories` too, please show if can** (2) My **AuthenticationHandler** extends `AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler` only, not `AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler`

Comment: (3) My **AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult** return `createHandlerResult(credential, this.principalFactory.createPrincipal(x), new ArrayList<>())`